# Smoother both in global planner and independent

Tags: navigation, ros2, ros-humble, path-planning, nav2

I was wondering what is the reasoning behind having both a smoother server (e.g., `a constrained smoother`) and defining a smoother in the planner server. Shouldn't the smoother server be enough on its own? Is there a difference between the two? Why are the default `w_smooth` parameters so different for the two (`0.3` when defined in the `planner server` and `2000000.0` when creating a `constrained smoother`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was provided in a comment by `Steven Macenski`

> This is just a simple post processing step for the nature of the Hybrid-A* method to make the quality "pop" with little variations due to discrete cost search. It takes well under 0.1ms so its not a heavy operation like the other Smoothers in the Smoother Server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no smoother in the planner server.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself correctly. If one configures for example the `SMAC Hybrid A*` planner, one should also define the `smoother` in this planner (as seen in the official configuration guide https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/smac/configuring-smac-hybrid.html). My question is why do we define a smoother there as well as a separate smoother server.  Shouldn't the smoother server be enough on its own? Why are the default `w_smooth` parameters so different for the two (`0.3` when defined in the planner server and `2000000.0` when creating a constrained smoother)?

Comment: This is just a simple post processing step for the nature of the Hybrid-A* method to make the quality "pop" with little variations due to discrete cost search. It takes well under 0.1ms so its not a heavy operation like the other Smoothers in the Smoother Server.